# Is there a polynomial with integral coefficients satisfying 2 conditions?

Tags: polynomials

Is there a polynomial $P(x)$ with integral coefficients s.t. $P(1+\sqrt[3]{2})=1+\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $P(1+\sqrt{5})=2+3\sqrt{5}$. I'm not good at this kind of problem, all I did up to now is just assuming $deg P=3,4,5$ and if I'm not wrong, $degP \geq6$. Help me

Comment: Funny my friend @GiangNam said he can solve this in 8 lines

Comment: Perhaps your friend can share his solution here.

Comment: You have accepted an answer that does not seem to have answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=(x-1)^3-2$, $g(x)=(x-1)^2-5$. The numbers $a=1+\sqrt[3]2$ and $b=1+\sqrt 5$ are roots respectively of $f$ asnd $g$.

It is a lot of work, but now you can solve the following system of congruences, using the Chinese remainder theorem applied to the Euclidean domain $\Bbb Q[x]$:

$$\begin{cases}P(x)\equiv x&\pmod f\\P(x)\equiv3x-1&\pmod g\end{cases}$$

So you get
$$P(a)=h_1(a)f(a)+a=a$$
$$P(b)=h_2(b)g(b)+3b-1=3b-1$$
as desired.

As it has been suggested in comments, $P$ may have non integer coefficients. In fact, using software I have found
$$P(x)=\frac1{121}(9x^4+16x^3-102x^2+223x-129)$$

I don't know if it is possible to find a polynomial $h_3(x)$ such that
$$P(x)+h_3(x)f(x)g(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$$

Comment: Very smart and elegant solution +1

Comment: Why does $P$ have integer coefficients?

Comment: Why do we have to use Q[x]. <f> and <g> are maximal ideal in Z[x],right?

Comment: @ajotatxe why not just Z[x]

Comment: @TrầnNguyênTry Because $\Bbb Z[x]$ is not an Euclidean domain.

Comment: @ajotatxe we need that? Chinese remaider theorem only needs comaximal ideals, right?

Comment: @TrầnNguyênTry, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591430/denominator-in-rational-gcd-of-integer-polynomials for instance.